# How to revoke all active tokens at once in Hashicorp Vault from a particular auth method?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have been looking for a way to revoke all active tokens at once from a particular auth method in Hashicorp Vault. For example, there's two auth configured in my case 1. Kubernetes 2. OIDC. I want to revoke all the active OIDC tokens. Please let me know if you know how we can list or revoke all the tokens.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [token auth backend API](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/auth/token) can do that for you.

With a token that has sudo privileges, you must:

1. List all of the accessors
2. Run through the list and keep the ones that have the path you want to revoke
3. Revoke them using the accessor

You did not specify a language, so here is a bash implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pass the name of the mount point in parameter or 
# through the $AUTH_MOUNT_POINT environment variable. Defaults to ldap
DEFAULT_MOUNT_NAME=${1-ldap}
: ${AUTH_MOUNT_POINT_NAME:=$DEFAULT_MOUNT_NAME}

for accessor in $(vault list --format json auth/token/accessors | jq -r .[])
do
    path=$(vault write --field path auth/token/lookup-accessor accessor=${accessor})
    if [[ "$path" =~ ^auth/$AUTH_MOUNT_POINT_NAME.* ]]
    then
        echo Revoking $path ...
        vault write auth/token/revoke-accessor accessor=${accessor}
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and responding. However, I revoked the lease itself instead of going for tokens and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ends up here from a web search:

The leases backend [`revoke-prefix`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/system/leases#revoke-prefix) can do this.

Note from the documentation:

> This requires `sudo` capability and access to it should be tightly controlled as it can be used to revoke very large numbers of secrets/tokens at once.

It can be accessed from the CLI by using the `-mode=path` flag in the [`vault token revoke`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/commands/token/revoke) command, e.g.

```
vault token revoke -mode=path auth/oidc
```